# Retrieve MySQL Default Value

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working with *MySqlConnect* for .Net (MySql.Data.dll states version 6.7.4.0) and running a local *MySQL Server* with *phpMyAdmin* via *XAMPP*.
*phpMyAdmin* appears to be at version *4.0.9* and *MySQL* itself is on Version *5.6.14* - MySQL Community Server (GPL).

The issue I am having relates to default values that I specified as binary values.
I was trying to export my database, and after several minutes of trial-and-error managed to use mysqldump to export my data as binary hex strings.
The problem is, that while the INSERT statements of the exported sql file were using perfectly nice and neat hexadecimal strings like I wanted, the DEFAULT specifiers of the structure weren't.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
  `map` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000',  
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000',  
  `ally` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',  
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `health` int(11) DEFAULT '400',  
  `shield` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `skill_menu` varbinary(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ÿÿÿÿ\0\0\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ',  
  `pvp_mod` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',  
  `inventory` varbinary(3024) NOT NULL,  
  `equipped_lasers` varbinary(955) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',  
  `boni` varbinary(955) NOT NULL,  
  `open_application` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `clan` varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I removed some entries for ease of reading, I hope you get the idea.
After searching around for a while, I figured nobody had apparently needed to ask the same thing, which means I was on my own.
I attempted just querying the structure manually, and writing out the default values properly, as hexadecimal strings (using x'hexstuff'), which was how I got them into the database in the first place.

To get the schema of the columns I used:

```
p_connection.GetSchema("Columns");
```

Where `p_connection` was a MySqlConnection.

This returns a DataTable that I am reading to figure out the default values of the columns.
The `COLUMN_DEFAULT` entry gives me exactly the same output as just exporting the data via mysqldump does.
So I figured I would need to go ahead and attempt converting that mess of letters and characters into properly formatted hex strings.
After I had done that, I was realizing that most of the default values were truncated or simply wrong (they were the same that would show up in phpMyAdmin's "Structure" tab of the table, just converted to hexadecimal, and what *phpMyAdmin* is displaying are not the actual default values (easily verified by inserting an empty row and seeing the default values)).
I double- and triple-checked that I was not altering the output of `COLUMN_DEFAULT` and I am not.

Since this issue purely revolves around the table structure (as in, the default values of the columns), and not around any specific data that I am running any algorithm on, I don't think that providing specific data is helping out here, so I'll leave that out.

Is there a way to retrieve the default values of the columns on a table in MySQL without having them be automatically and behind my back falsely converted to strings?

As of now, I am considering a workaround where I just insert an element into the table without any arguments, so that all values default. Then I can load that element back in and check out the values it has, which should all be defaulted.
My problem is, that using this as an export method would be horrible, because it would not only cause unnecessary load, but also increase possible `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns, just for figuring out default values.
Before you ask: I have looked at `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FOR tableName`, and it behaves exactly the same as my approach of loading column default values.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the values of columns in a way that doesn't coerce them to ASCII, you can do this query to the information schema. `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` is a shortcut for querying this table. The important thing is the ability to code the `COLUMN_DEFAULT` as hex here.

```
 SELECT COLUMN_TYPE,
    HEX(COLUMN_DEFAULT) 
   FROM information_schema.Columns 
  WHERE table_schema <> 'information_schema'
    AND COLUMN_TYPE LIKE '%ob'
```

Obviously you'll use `WHERE` clauses that are appropriate to your table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I ran "SELECT HEX( COLUMN_DEFAULT ) 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'users'" and it returned the same truncated and wrong results as my own method for converting the trippy weird default values to hexadecimal. I created another emptry entry into my table to verify that these results were actually wrong. The created entries' values defaulted to the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the values saved under information_schema.Columns are buggy (or so I think, anyways).

Retrieving the default values via

`SELECT DEFAULT(columnName) FROM tableName`
 returns correct and complete values.

Best Regards